# AJAX returns HTML with the response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this Javascript on my html page:

```
$('#om-dropdown').change(function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    var data = {
        "OM": id
    }
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    alert(data);
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(arguments);
            console.warn(xhr.responseText);
            alert(" Can't do because: " + error);
        },
        success:function(data){
            alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["forca_armada"]);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

and this is part of the php code on the same page:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' &&
    isset($_POST["OM"]) && !empty($_POST["OM"])){
    $OMid = $_POST["OM"];
    $selectedOM = $mapper->getOMbyId($OMid);
    if ($selectedOM != null){
        send_OM_info($selectedOM);
    }
}

function send_OM_info($OM){
    $return = $_POST;
    $return["forca_armada"] = $OM->getForcaArmada();
    $return["json"] = json_encode($return);
    echo json_encode($return);
    exit();
}
```

My problem is that AJAX should only return the encrypted ids of OM's, but it is returning that plus the html page bellow the `echo json_encode($return);` even though there is a `exit()` right after the echo. What seems to be the problem here?

Here is the AJAX response:

```
string(56) "F3eDjfjuAG839xXzRTi2bwdug5cCRlJkk/ud7JhCfuD/Tnh8WhaZunme"
string(56) "pwX1NNJRjxjGauOqX4ulcH7z7VXIhrj4yOQ4v+Dj3tSioRdgDKM2L+E5"
string(56) "lCy65DD8dc0hArq0dQjyCGuzhAXgWyhaTp1rXEKyFRry1SPmhmvnwW8U"
string(56) "PZbjG+gS7cUdI48TktBjFbF4EbW4p8VaXSS9baz2UECVpDZCiigRxukj"
string(56) "s8LTTwsLdRSSD563iVy0WJ36Gl8FSMiz1Pfmt/SepLK5FJxOW2gau1C2"
string(56) "og846u5NieO60ODIS1OZVHRwSV4I96Z7XFELWLsAnj3F212Kdj0rKNwo"
string(56) "7SoGN49esOOx4Xu2Y7K7Y2GqlMcHOmEqvmqcIsrcQwPPEaFwdDzMbwl+"
string(56) "YAQOOoosX+huRLqETESh1mBMR34ybqLXlrsB1F44/SkS4k3QUHsEzMtn"
string(56) "zYECSR3S/7j2KdNB8kZFPYnvgAWaWUzy+yn0bZA58r0wIc1wMzh7YgTT"
string(56) "82MUCiVlyHL/N+zeacX2n8BWrKkr12F5DIfPFRqL3qLes+h7MRskTC4Q"
string(56) "1PQkUOK2efsxfu1bWiFDBW2Nqi2pshTx/0WJdLWP+8X2fx5G7QCkecAl"
string(56) "kepEICm3oUs5lbkyVoehyOJ08pOifngFsAnBk9umaBbHGu/Ha03gwHm5"
string(56) "5284bA2tu/XdTzNR1VLp9B6VIl4wJugVZ2URc+PQRZ6N4sAZGGCxPyMC"
string(56) "IT0i+qEu6NnuGq7k2v6IWqGffrGDuOYybvn5M1HRfnhe82oel6kDziqf"
string(56) "bZMn9PprUzQze8sPOH6GPdi0rWTixBGzKzlpR21wmjtJkY+I80TUaIyS"
string(56) "f/R3VN7FW8bbVxAhwK/Bq90y6z+TPbuvk/2ac1myUoUAvBUcLHSUVtU5"
string(56) "P0lQYa/T4KvSS6qAZuCHRhdRuTxDHpDZR9dTRSBCSyJPfjqmK6GkasnF"
string(56) "96eNtObNpZJCPxXL6+0s1nvU3WCIXpRbDkX6vwvUuM9+rs0W7rQRJJEB"
string(56) "xuKiaIbZpdm9i9GM36ladDe9SZIdnJl9CqsygIkwoquYHk8gduKm1kc0"
string(56) "E0nxA9iR5UTb97KJ7I5JboQMqSoHtO2/qqal7C0Ge03xWz7MwIzvvFoZ"
string(56) "AAMERYBjfuw0F2MXL19eSvygGRdbWOBuoXnYhJLRjSMxkf3pGkq/RhNa"
string(56) "nwurra6BqM83UNdCGF11QqfJx7Xf+EnYB8Q4UmKfK1Jh5/BMl/sYov9W"
string(56) "AaO7PwNcrE+OP0Hoe+IK46G8hloAhx3J9jcQaB3MfA681+1+Tpyc7+1H"
string(56) "K8kqJo+6Sp2+kJsqGIEXxNEK6SrUA0CMkvIF7b5tQ3BeYVbIQalVD9Yb"
string(56) "9Ta7JqffN7AqZhI2sQbq9SMCGSxYecKG2E7KWXUS6t5zXM3Sk6+NkWPn"
string(56) "TEB9yE/0nsYSib8lMEFwXkDqdUbv1NtD78IOq3HHqEYbKAnJx5gi2hGF"
string(56) "JjiBsOtUOTmXTDe/tF3HFOH47uME0NdjAP1j2ZRjIv617do7OBNcuUbg"
string(56) "Ms+nQdNVY+AfWU8Z2Vq5JdZSXdRudYK2taM1r0yBkOO09lEDUIiIs7Nq"
string(56) "4vwcDGoIaU0br7Ec88fLCm2rKQmLO6VfK3zVSLITP295Dt9hkmU4dLVY"
string(56) "huyw8HRt4Mf+JVu5dffoGHIDzNgRVee0oQcMzu7NDuwu2GcVNrEcH1nC"
string(56) "BZN7Vu18kW9lNtcsryHujR4X5iqaS3fyPj+TWjoFMHOtEkEjJdULz7cq"
string(56) "sIjI35mTP0hwAHOT0x5j1epq8N2Vo9IfOQ7xLSYlcVRTzplfhzTCqqzt"
string(56) "YhcmhdPKAc+OWd/rBog/5cHubx9lSEnq2PM7+I+py8vzmYvXkqTwEq78"
string(56) "ZbeA8B1dxrVvR2caYTq5CzwJm2VWWS/PKZwFuw6FNlK2M0MdXFzEgg0q"
string(56) "HTMr3tvDwFRvm2+x1T52gHG8DIW4ObOJekuccaUocx2JrejNy+sESGmG"
string(56) "BbCh9NgwY1InmhHkf6ofuPxG6+h6vBo5m96GxSe/JMNP8jrcEEBZHz4V"
string(56) "uXkvt/jbOKezAxPOKoCzmsuizUriZOJQhYphvjRj2LPTppD56+ZyMiUn"
string(56) "SsO1ZDK3N49Q97G7RhudqwfccOPGTnN3TvFbz+3JS87BmqHeRzUT7rMN"
string(56) "vn/zNey4IIhVtg0+v29TOe0dNskyAzN2ELeyZnrFGYrS1E8QbCPhNFdJ"
string(56) "zwkqGuRgZK2k41QJjVRtwqoYyy9GJ3/yvYAaCm683LbwzUXoLYM9hzvU"
string(56) "kx3p3CON84hG/ywh/lQbWdckEqecazrT01dWPgSf9uDkq94wOqiuni5e"
string(56) "dgEKDUoKJfyml+6ghOSMMNxQuKl2VhkuqGQP+XaDqnn6KnFtdgJQa+ci"
string(56) "OF0XgLxSQsXox4mfW+vCnnYB46FNeDaj34ggNnFKKnO4qtFMwv8pB7JH"
string(56) "exKalsI4MQvfVUaobN6sNLJgDg0R+a7tTTA7i8iKOFia3YYR1r4yI4Uu"
string(56) "K5FVoqfFO3jJN1idZyZMNda+efS36b5GcqzcOP/EsBSaY4ZYmJp8gWlk"
string(56) "kFxc1MViaaJz0j8X62HqI7RNZjyh05dgEWGQgKNHVQIbCxMUhG/3b4QR"
string(60) "dYRfWF1jft88BkmY36MH3LrNjd3LdmFzmNT+0fGIDIY3YeagFxJTMR9ZgA=="
string(60) "vJCa7WyQUYlDvPNgn1QD4K1z7fTgI1/liv7mG7aRRVGI6M62W9EDV/fRrA=="
string(60) "1FijGeGIosb6gVtDg2CC9BNBOnYDyC4RzSsSsMBd8kcsN/ImB9cimpWanw=="
string(60) "vwgS9yzlPJ3S4MFEto8WU5vPWZb3mGq7/hvkc4I3RIuLv1oV+7qqMpYXeA=="
string(60) "m1MkQAcSzlTuj09cRk0TfNKupuBfN+qKYvAUuOk4bV/6F3ZmuCO1RLNnZw=="
string(60) "qwlfv7RgNRKHG/ysLVTtOKtRBs4Z8/4FF0DsEf3Q3VrH7LWXpdThW4rb4Q=="
string(60) "k9CpO6DSXDqX5WNeUNksOPJK7WnCtSEopMTmj5Dq3lUXo7zh5V15J2gJtQ=="
string(60) "VcOVgoP7YwxBPIVqfT8Ql3mAE+6wfeI3CzG0hSRv1xeHRE9duHCo8NZC9g=="
string(60) "5UGg10a+WmzOmjeb2HFUSaun3QARDZdcfwdlwxNKQ+4fE1KXQvu/I3djgA=="
string(60) "fVXwPP+71goZog/D/oHHm3GssL120/ug4k987xNb1Sj21b6yoLihVgVPTw=="
string(60) "Mb7g7dhN9tKrDBaq8WdCPH1SwApELEFrwA6y0094dFIevx6q443THkXmQw=="
string(60) "TkJh980/kk8VQA3QlpSWY4ff+UkSMaxpUJ8U6mS9bGhsufB15PK3vgNQWw=="
string(60) "H2oJnlqY/4Izgo6xBhhHYlxH3Q87Fn/5t+ymVh+H6n2O7ArvDIY6iD53sA=="
string(60) "E0UpgB+q3Qf9TxvHsCVJ0MT016DVauZ14/AlduYz/PZy6qCsLsCHJcpWJw=="
string(60) "RMzRMP2PkpGiiYFRgII7aZdNgZRhXkGIvrb2YhZLBddNZmXvNGWf7bLsdw=="
string(60) "uf5+fLek+geVpbPbn2D9AnrEYopyRUkVTT2+W7hMl+Mv8GisPsznQ20X+Q=="
string(60) "xxu3/1hpi/irs7D4Eq/NBsHmVdBLm3p2kxn/wo/6+GQz1sY53u2EUvQ3zA=="
string(60) "KeG9Kkm254B09xLwPjs19Emu5ZkazPEC3WWN78F5769idZqlfT5IIXyxPw=="
string(60) "nuOobIIzqI8BvUZIwQ2nsOdJqQmqSMuDD9Edy56qSlYLcHLofDO923TuIA=="
string(60) "ydrFoEayM8czV6vZgDEtGVJ88KzNZM8vrnVe4O7zlCLTB3VLvpk4Po21mw=="
string(60) "HBuSpchkmCDG9e/SWKLNLPgRYf4+yRtqbH0tlD26AcQsNxzpHCSECr4S0Q=="
string(60) "wAJMDkKC9YhPI7DZ9c0KS5PjN/dfeUQ1d4XRqnzWhF362mVCpPZdR9Hi4w=="
string(60) "KAkWQbrf62smiaTBjInfmDEN3GaijvUx/+85WgLNAYy0w2lAq5RQSHhgBA=="
string(60) "AsfJfANYdRz7fcr337jVScJT8w23LdYYpscRskIGdOIwJq54IGtpoqwAUw=="
string(60) "I5Fp9nXnJcguORGJYu0SRzvy6hhjHIfYBYp0UMvoHEellOa8ULP5PYlF8w=="
string(60) "DdTYPpdbZP25VIBaMdensnPbAVj0QJBC28oCmcu6yQJCHE/FGyfmCuRNXw=="
string(60) "5Wccas1zozFCLokNuI+Bm73/jLhP2mMwQSlJownXxWuNao1bX6NM8/OFaw=="
string(60) "tnfpnsTqpPxswZrWdbG7OifIYVto+/9QVbJoVmcVYdKoDNrzzd2WwJZbDA=="
string(60) "GUt0muEAIflw6hydKNbvf9+Uy43Bjf4JjE7OgTx1DBAjA3Roo7X04GYCQQ=="
string(60) "ka2HI/bGMULLu3EOmkXLMGcVg+DVIcdlZSMJF+rlgJOxmy3Uszku5atAhw=="
string(60) "uj3VF17pqJO2JnWTxPTeSR2T4G8xlujkqLqOnuEy/xLYwy5uhpo7eRW10g=="
string(60) "Bf+xJjhfkvlBhAVG3f+qIna2xUoN390JtWE9SJ4dOXOZnuWdl35c+0pI2A=="
string(60) "JADFWar/NnhLP2OS7GkMPRoptcnZwGlZKwvpbRQMAEEio95HZyL+A1rL4A=="
string(60) "yE9uYzFYBYnrYnaQjqkBWjMvD5F06CYN2bWpaQyuCyEDaE2pGH7QOcQqvg=="
string(60) "9KYVn4fhi+dRVqKyHZEhtYuLkRbF3VsmUBnZcavrnGAa9h0Cco7UJ7bruw=="
string(60) "l+xlGBYotnb358d58nS1WJvfKHyd63N7cV0xCtRnVUEUkYwaZLhkTH6+GQ=="
string(60) "Q24CdAbJSo7TJP4ZsbDggmb9Grh0QWroTyOYhP28lTRK4cuu5tBwX7DKvw=="
string(60) "ruTlrgUuuXyFbflXkxIQGr4wpfxXC27nXVyebo9f1wI5Mvn5zUUz8TUbrw=="
string(60) "MpF08Tj9LDt3j6iCEXmmB/+YVAmwWhEoQLwUQuqXnDTxb7z89TyGbb4V/g=="
string(60) "atq6/tQefw7Xm3X+ZuyTJr9q5OFRq0EreFJOtVbRvKuRGN3wGebuZXGQ0g=="
string(60) "A9H5uFKsAlnLYI9TIga/y0f1Ooh1T3HLH7+sJwVVW2xhAwL3qlwNQAQnkg=="
string(60) "kwY+LoDGVaEpj8N4Jq/O1uSb9HNo89oG9gSRGF+FtLGzgsk12sUv6x85lw=="
string(60) "jsYzzkfd6K5ksGSm3hR9XtxZjrUnjMwmAFYaAw3KQCxUljl8rxNI4EYZbA=="
string(60) "WM2MS70lCT34b+fecJrbDzNXozUi0mO/1/Z6BfPYz72jAMnZ3cFAhGPr2g=="
string(60) "+89j66U5ciGQo0aZM0/+P9nuPcdzmRrAFLX/xr7k3G/APm976bN6MRWZiQ=="
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>ASC | Principal</title>

    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="../images/favicon_package_v0.16/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="../images/favicon_package_v0.16/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="../images/favicon_package_v0.16/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="../images/favicon_package_v0.16/site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="../images/favicon_package_v0.16/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

</head>

<body class="top-navigation">

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">
        <div class="row border-bottom white-bg">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-static-top" role="navigation">

        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">STM</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>
        </button>

        <!--</div>-->
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a aria-expanded="false" role="button" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Consulta</a>
                    <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="">Conselho Permanente</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Conselho Especial</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a aria-expanded="false" role="button" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Novo Conselho</a>
                    <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="">Conselho Permanente</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Conselho Especial</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="vl"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a aria-expanded="false" role="button" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Cadastro</a>
                    <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="cadastro-militar.php">Militar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Posto</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Organização Militar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Força Armada</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a aria-expanded="false" role="button" href="#" class="not-active" >Relatórios</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a aria-expanded="false" role="button" href="#" class="not-active" >Sorteio</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="logout.php">
                        <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Sair
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>        <div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <h2>Cadastro Militar</h2>
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                        <a href="../index.php">Principal</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item">
                        <a>Cadastro</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">
                        <strong>Militar</strong>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="ibox ">
                        <div class="ibox-title">
                            <h5>Entre com as informações do militar</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ibox-content">
                            <form method="post">
                                <div class="form-group  row"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">CPF</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10"><input name="cpf" type="text" class="form-control"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group  row"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Nome</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10"><input name="fname" type="text" class="form-control"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group  row"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Sobrenome</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10"><input name="lname" type="text" class="form-control"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Organização Militar</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <select id="om-dropdown" class="form-control m-b" name="account">
                                            <option></option>
                                            #Long list of <option> here                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group row"><label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Posto</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <select class="form-control m-b" name="account">
                                            <option>option 1</option>
                                            <option>option 2</option>
                                            <option>option 3</option>
                                            <option>option 4</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="the-return">

                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="footer">
            <div>
                <strong>Copyright</strong> Example Company &copy; 2014-2018
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<!-- Mainly scripts -->
<script src="../js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script>
    $('#om-dropdown').change(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        var data = {
            "OM": id
        }
        data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
        alert(data);
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(arguments);
                console.warn(xhr.responseText);
                alert(" Can't do because: " + error);
            },
            success:function(data){
                // $(".the-return").html(
                //     "Posto: " + data["posto"] + "<br />JSON: " + data["json"]
                // );

                alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["forca_armada"]);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>

error   @   cadastro-militar.php:179
i   @   jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2
fireWith    @   jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2
A   @   jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4
(anonymous) @   jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4
load (async)        
send    @   jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4
ajax    @   jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4
(anonymous) @   cadastro-militar.php:173
dispatch    @   jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3
q.handle    @   jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3
ListPicker._handleMouseUp
```

The first console alert I get is indeed the encrypted id of the selected list element, but the second alert states:

```
Can't do because: SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
```

### EDIT 1

Here is the beggining of the complete file:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("../controller/loginFuncs.php");
\asc\checkLogin();

require_once '../controller/database/PDO_Conn.php';
require_once '../controller/database/MySQL_DataMapper.php';

try {
    $pdo = \asc\PDO_Conn::getInstance();
    $mapper = new \asc\MySQL_DataMapper($pdo);

    $result = $mapper->fetchAllOMs();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

function send_OM_info($OM){
    $return = $_POST;
    $return["forca_armada"] = $OM->getForcaArmada();
    $return["json"] = json_encode($return);
    echo json_encode($return);
}

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' &&
    isset($_POST["OM"]) && !empty($_POST["OM"])){
    $OMid = $_POST["OM"];
    $selectedOM = $mapper->getOMbyId($OMid);
    if ($selectedOM != null){
        send_OM_info($selectedOM);
    }
    exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>ASC | Principal</title>

    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    # The rest os the HTML page and the JQuery script is at the bottom
```

Comment: What version of jquery? Depending on the version `type: 'POST'` and `method: 'POST'` can perform a `GET` request.

Comment: JQuery Version 3.1.1

Comment: @Kisaragi - Since the OP is using `type`, it should work on all jQuery versions. `method` is just an alias added in jQuery 1.9.0.

Comment: Thank you for you reply @MagnusEriksson the php code is indeed at the top of the file, before any HTML code. If I place the `exit()` after the `if ($selectedOM != null){ ... }` then the page doesn't get loaded in the first place.

Comment: It should be inside the first `if` but after the inner `if`. If your page isn't loaded at all when you do that, then you must have placed it wrong. Update your code to show how you added it.

Comment: Right, the page loaded but the AJAX response still constrains HTML, I will edit the question to post the beginning of the complete file.

Comment: I also don't see where all the `string(56) "F3eDjfjuAG839xXzRTi2bwdug5cCRlJkk/ud7JhCfuD/Tnh8WhaZunme"` and such would come from? You're not having any `var_dump()` anywhere?

Comment: It is inside the `<select>` but I omitted it because Stack overflow limited the character on my question to 30.000, instead I placed a comment there `#Long list of <option> here`. Here is how one option would look like `<option value="vqw9ewOBQhN/OYvSc8rVldwGS/fZQi6NBVhN9WpL16ImcWwzIfBWTXUI">Comando Militar do Oeste (CMO)</option>`, the value of the option is the encrypted id of that OM in the database, with that I can query the OM in the database and return relevant data back to the page. But HTML is being returned together with the data.

Comment: Try and remove `data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);` completely and just pass the object you already have. No need to serialize  or use `$.param()` at all.

Comment: I did that and then when I try to `console.log(arguments)` I just get `[object Object]` and the error persists.

Comment: You mean when you do `alert(data)`? You can't alert objects. You need to `console.log()`-them. The `console.log(argument)` is in your error-callback (and `argument` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177212/discussion-between-alexandre-krabbe-and-magnus-eriksson).

Comment: I have some recommendations. 1. Put the PHP code in it's own file and call that file. 2. Open the browsers dev tools and check the network tab and see what is actually sent when the ajax request is made. 3. Add some debugging to your PHP file (dump `$_SERVER` and `$_POST`) and see what they actually contain. It seems like your first `if`-expression doesn't evaluate as true

Answer (score 0):

You could enclose the source of your HTML page in a `else` block.

```
function send_OM_info($OM){
    $return = $_POST;
    $return["forca_armada"] = $OM->getForcaArmada();
    $return["json"] = json_encode($return);
    echo json_encode($return);
}

if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' &&
    isset($_POST["OM"]) && !empty($_POST["OM"])){
    $OMid = $_POST["OM"];
    $selectedOM = $mapper->getOMbyId($OMid);
    if ($selectedOM != null){
        send_OM_info($selectedOM);
    }
} else { ?> 
<!-- YOUR HTML CODE HERE --> 
<?php } ?>
```

However, you should also consider moving your AJAX handling elsewhere, where it can be decoupled from your HTML (View) code.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but the error persists even with the else block